# How do I exclude python dependencies needing to be present to check using the python plugin

Tags: python, sonarqube

Some engineers in our organization are starting to use python but we find we must have the dependencies, produced by third parties, present for the analysis to be done successfully.

Is there a way to exclude python dependencies needing to be accessible for the code we produce to be analyzed?

We are using SonarQube 5.6.6 with the Sonar Python 1.8.0.1496 plugin installed.

Comment: What "analysis" are you referring to?

Comment: dependencies are required for analysis and you want to exclude them. i don't understand what you are trying to achieve. can you explain more

Comment: Do you main exclude them from code coverage?

Comment: The third party pieces will be available when the program executes, but Prasad and Jeron, thanks for your replies.  We do not want to have them included in coverage nor in problem detection analysis. We will have no control over such code and do not want this to be part of what we can improve on. Also, when initial analysis of the code is done the third party dependencies may not have been pulled in yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude dependencies with the `sonar.exclusions` property in the `sonar-project.properties` file.

For example:
`sonar.exclusions=third-parties/lib/**/* , other/lib/**/*`

See [Narrowing the Focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-Patterns)

Comment: Thanks Alban. I knew that worked for Java and some other languages, but I did not know it would work for the Python interpretive language where the third party pieces needed to be in place for the program to run.